# How to extend the braintree module in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, braintree

Currently, I'm migrating my custom magento1 **braintree** module into magento2. In magento1 I'm using the gene braintree extension. There are some methods I'm extended but the same methods are not there in magento2. can you please tell how to extend the methods.

Comment: Why don't you try gene module for Magento 2? So you want to migrate its tables and data to Magento 2?

Comment: in magento1 braintree module is not there so I installed but in magento2 braintree module is default, so I want to extend the default one.

Comment: Please find the module for Magento 2    https://marketplace.magento.com/paypal-module-braintree.html which extends default Braintree module with additional features such as Apple pay, Google pay etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I need only credit card option. Not required the othere payment methods

Comment: So the default extension does it right? So you are trying to do some other Customisations to the module